# Get Instagram Insights with Powerbi

Tags: powershell, powerbi-desktop, instagram-api

I need to connect Powerbi to Instagram account and get de Instagram insights data!

I do a search and find a connector on github, but it doesn't work with the new Instagram api version, when I change the client_id and Client_secret it shows me the following message Application inactive, how do I make the connector work?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.